# What's wrong with my C code?

Tags: c, types

```
float x = 4.5;
main()
{
    float y,float f(); 
    x*=2.0;
    y=f(x);
    printf("\n%f%f",x,y);
}

float f (float a)

{
    a+=1.3;
    x-=4.5;
    return(a+x);
}
```

This program is from the book: Let us C, by Yashwant kanetkar. And the output it says is 4.500000 5.800000. I get error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: program doesn't even compile!

Comment: Try to use `float y, f(float);` instead.

Comment: [1]. When you ask a compilation error question, always include the exact error message (without editing). [2]. Don't read from Yashwant Kanetkar, it is very outdated. Refer some [good book](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562303/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//global variable x, can be accessed from anywhere
float x = 4.5;

//inform the compiler, that a function that is defined later, but it exists in the code, and to use it before it's defined, we need to know how it looks like:
float f(float a);

//I need to specify what my main function returns, typically "int"
int main()
{
    //local variable for saving the result in:
    float y;

    //multiply x, with 2, and save the result in x:
    x*=2.0;

    //run the function:
    y=f(x);

    //show the result:
    printf("\n%f%f",x,y);

    //return a value to let the OS know how the program ended (0 is success)
    return 0;
}

//define the function
float f (float a)
{ 
    //whatever a is provided, add 1.3 to it before doing anything else
    a+=1.3;
    //subtract 4.5 from the global variable, before doing anything else:
    x-=4.5;
    //return the sum of a and x, as the result of this function.
    return(a+x);
}
```

the math here is:

```
x = 4.5
x = (x * 2) = 9
a = (x = 9) = 9
a = (a + 1.3) = 10.3
x = (x - 4.5) = 4.5
y = a + x = (4.5 + 10.3) = 14.8
```

Comment: Informing the compiler was important, I forgot that. Your explanation brought clarity, Thanks.

Comment: I think this line: `y = a + x = (4.5 + 10.3) = 15.8` should be  `y = a + x = (4.5 + 10.3) = 14.8`.

Answer (score 0):

**Point 1:**

Remove `float f();` from `main()`. Declare `float f();` outside `main()`. Thus, it will serve the purpose of *forward declaration*.

**Point 2.**

Remove the `,` and add a `;` after `float y`.

**Point 3.**

`main()` should be `int main(void)`.

Note: Consider adding an explicit `return` statement at the end of `main()`. Though is is not mandatory, but is considered a good practice.

Answer (score 0):

float y,float f();

Use semicolon after `float y`

```
float y;
```

And `float f();` //(wrong prototype). you need to pass argument to this function.

No need to declare function inside main. you can remove `float f();` from your `main()` function.

main not returning any value

Use

```
int main()
{
   //your code
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you declare `f()`:

```
float y,float f();
```

you aren't using a prototype. So when the call to `f()` is made:

```
y=f(x);
```

the `float` argument `x` is being promoted by the compiler to a `double` type.

To solve the problem, declare the function using a full prototype:

```
float f(float a);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to declare functions like variables in your main. 2. Also, main() should be `int main()`. 3. Define/ declare your function before using it.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
float x = 4.5;

float f (float a)

{
a+=1.3;
x-=4.5;
return(a+x);
}
int main(void) {
// your code goes here
float y;

x*=2.0;
y=f(x);
printf("\n%f%f",x,y);
return 0;
}
```

Ideone link: http://ideone.com/W7V1Qr

Comment: But if I declare main() first and then the other function, why does it show error: ag.c:13:7: error: conflicting types for ‘f’
 float f (float a)
       ^
ag.c:9:7: note: previous implicit declaration of ‘f’ was here
     y=f(x);

Comment: That is because whenever you refer to a function, the compiler should already know about that function.

Comment: Yes, Fundamentals! just forgot. Got it now though. Thanks.